# Are high court rulings precedential?

Tags: united-kingdom, rules-of-court, precedent

What courts if any are bound by past rulings of the high court, whether civil or criminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Precedent within the High Court

See *Willers v Joyce (No 2)* [[2016] UKSC 44](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2016/44.html), para. 9, which explains the default rule:

> So far as the High Court is concerned, [puisne judges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puisne_judge#United_Kingdom) are not technically bound by decisions of their peers, but **they should generally follow a decision of a court of co-ordinate jurisdiction unless there is a powerful reason for not doing so**. And, where a first instance judge is faced with a point on which there are two previous inconsistent decisions from judges of co-ordinate jurisdiction, then the second of those decisions should be followed in the absence of cogent reasons to the contrary ...

Courts have not developed precise rules of when a judge would be justified in deviating from previous co-ordinate precedent, but one observer suggests that judges have looked to the following factors (Lewis Graham, "[Strong Decisions and Stare Decisis in co-ordinate Courts](https://doi.org/10.1080/09615768.2023.2236733)" (2023) Kings L.J):

- the rank of the judge who rendered the previous judgment
- the function in which the court was operating
- the emanence of the particular judge
- the number of judges who heard the case

#### Precedent between the High Court and County Courts

See *Howard De Walden Estates Ltd v Les Aggio & Ors* [[2007] EWCA Civ 499](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2007/499.html), at paras 86-95:

> The County Court is a lower court than the High Court in the hierarchy of the legal system of England and Wales and is bound by the decisions of the High Court, as well as those of courts above ...

The Court of Appeal said that this is the case even for High Court judgments where it was sitting as a court of first instance.

> The fact that both the High Court and the County Courts are lower than the Court of Appeal, to which appeals lie, does not mean that the High Court and the County Court are courts of co-ordinate jurisdiction for the purposes of the doctrine of stare decisis.

This reasoning has been criticized as being mere *obiter* and for failing to meaningfully deal with various concerns or alternative approachs: Phillip Morgan, "[Doublethink and District Judges – High Court Precedent in the County Court](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2667099)" (2013) Journal of Legal Studies.

Comment: And wait so does this suggest that county court is largely (to some significantly strong extent) bound by its own past rulings whether or not these are published and distributed?